# How to fix differents columns width with tabularx?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, width

I want to create a table with 100% width of the page so i'm using the package tabularx.
I need to set the width of the columns, so I decided to separate the table into 20 separate columns. This allows me to assign a number of columns for a single cell using a multicolumn.
I found an example and I adapted it to my case.

For example when I've :

```
\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax
```

There are 3 numbers in this :

- 7 hsize : 7 columns
- 12 tabcolsep : there are 12 tabcolsep inside the new multicolumn
- 6 arrayrulewidth : there are 6 arrayrulewidth inside the new multicolumn

We can simplify this :

If we have we want a multicolumn{N}, we'll have N hsize, (N-1)*2 tabcolsep and N-1 arrayrulewidth

For the following example, it works :

```
\documentclass{article}

    % Français
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}

    % Images
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}

    % Tables
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    % Custom Header
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyhead[L]{
      \begin{tabular}[b]{l}
        \textbf{BLABLABLA}  \tabularnewline
        BLABLABLA \tabularnewline
        BLABLABLA \tabularnewline
    \end{tabular}   
  }%
  \fancyhead[R]{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \centering\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{example-image}%
      \end{tabular}
  }%
}
\pagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{textcomp}   


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20 \\ \hline

\multicolumn{12}{|>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr12\hsize+22\tabcolsep+11\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{TEST}
&
\multicolumn{8}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{TEST} \\ \hline

\textbf{N°}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Tests}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Res}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Modif}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline



1
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline

2
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline



\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tab is working]

But now, if we try to put another similar row like that :

```
3
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline
```

That gives me :

[image: Tab is not working]

EDIT : You can now just copy paste my document code.

If you find a solution, please put other columns to check if it's working great.

If you're asking why 20 columns, it's because I want to assign a number of columns for a certain cell. (Like 12/20 of the page width or 17/20 of the page width)

The first row with columns (from 1 to 20), it's just to check if columns are not bigger than normal size for nothing. (debug)

EDIT-2 :

I agree to use tabular rather than tabularx but how to do this :

- Table full width of the page
- Cells must accept multiple lines
- The number inside cells correspond to the ratio of the cell to the table

[image: Cells ratio to the table]

(The first cell of the last row is a multirow 2)

In that case, how to do this with tabular and not tabularx ?

Comment: please make it easier for people to help by posting complete aritcle class documents that show the problem, not just fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks the @david-carlisle 's help and for other people who would eventually look for a solution to this. Let's see the following code and picture :

```
\noindent\begin{tabular}{| 
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    p{\dimexpr 0.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
    }
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{12}{|p{\dimexpr 0.6\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{8}{p{\dimexpr 0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{20}{|p{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l lLorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{20}{|p{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l lLorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline

N°
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}{Lorem ipsum} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The code produces :

[image: Tab corresponding to the code]

Answer (score 3):

If I add the 4th row I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{??}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20 \\ \hline
\textbf{N°}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Tests}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Res}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Modif}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\centering\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline


1
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline


2
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline

3
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline

4
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{7}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr7\hsize+12\tabcolsep+6\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Lorem ipsum}
&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{OK} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But do you really need 20 columns? if the 1-20 is just for debugging rather than data it would seem that you only really have 5 columns.

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I was looking for, I updated my used packages to correctly explain my problem. I completely updated my post.

Comment: @Nulji that's why questions should always have a test document:-)  OK I get same now. Looks odd, I'll try to debug later (I would never use `tabularx` for this anyway, even though I wrote it, but it probably should work...)  You know the column widths you want so it's simpler (and a lot quicker) to simply use a tabular.

Comment: I did a second edit to know how to do after this change.

Comment: @Nulji just use arithmetic as you were doing before if \zz is textwidth after subtracting the right number of tabcolsep and arrayrulewidth you want a preamble of `|p{.05\zz}|p{.35\zz}|p{.35\zz}|p{.15\zz}|p{.1\zz}|}`

Comment: Thanks but how can I create 12/20 and 8/20 column at the first row THEN you're code line ? This is my biggest question (how to have 12/20 and 8/20 column at the first row, then 5 differents widths columns at the next row of the same table)

Comment: Moreover, I can't use tabular. I tried to create a table with tabular and only one column `p{\textwidth}` and This exceeded the maximum width of the page (The text on my document can't exceed the end of the bottom line of the header and with this column created, this exceed the end of the bottom line of the header)

Comment: @Nulji a tabular with a single `p{\textwidth}` column is `\textwidth+2\tabcolsep` wide as _you_ explain in the calculations in your question.